# Woocommerce, wc_customer_bought_product возвращает не верный результат

Tags: php, woocommerce

Использую обработчик `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` для обработки заказа.
В коде делается проверка, есть ли такой товар у текущего пользователя, но проблема в том, что это новый пользователь и ошибка указывает что такой товар уже есть, и возможно функция `wc_customer_bought_product` берёт данные из кэша?
До этого делал тест этим же юзером и удалил его.
Как это поправить, чтобы данные не брались из кэша?

```
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if(!empty($variation_id)){
            $hasBought = wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $variation_id );
            if($hasBought){
                wc_add_notice( __( 'Registration is prohibited.','wc' ), 'notice' );

                $order->update_status( 'cancelled' );
                return false;
            }
        }
```

В функции `wc_customer_bought_product` есть такие строчки:

```
$transient_name    = 'wc_customer_bought_product_' . md5( $customer_email . $user_id );
$transient_version = WC_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'orders' );
$transient_value   = get_transient( $transient_name );
```

может быть здесь берутся данные из кэша?

Comment: кто-то подскажет?

Comment: нет, данные не брались из кэша, просто существовали прошлые заказы, проблема решилась, нужно было удалить прошлые заказы